# Is there a Delphi dropdown notification component?

Tags: delphi, components, vcl, ui-design

You know how in Firefox, if something happens that requires your attention but isn't immediately urgent enough to require a modal dialog, it will drop down a little strip at the top of the tab with a question on it?  I'd like to be able to put functionality like that in a Delphi app, but I don't know if there's a component for that.  Does anyone know of one?

Answer (score 2):

I have made one using a TPanel and few lines of code. But you can try something like  TMS Adv Panel http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advpanel.asp.